# an error occurred while updating the entries. see the innerexception for details. savechanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

using this code i have no error message.
when i excute my program i face some error "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."
and my program are crashed.. database dont save any field.

```
`Driver data = new Driver();
                     if (txtCallSign.Text != null)
                     {
                        data.callSign = Convert.ToInt32(txtCallSign.Text);
                     }
                    data.firstName = txtFirstName.Text;
                    data.middleName = txtMname.Text;
                    data.lastName = txtLastName.Text;
                    data.address1 = txtStreet.Text;
                    data.address2 = txtArea.Text;
                    data.address3 = txtCity.Text;
                    data.postCode = txtPostalCode.Text;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTelephone.Text))
                    {
                        data.telephone = Convert.ToInt64(txtTelephone.Text);
                    }
                     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtmobile.Text))
                     {
                        data.mobile = Convert.ToInt64(txtmobile.Text);
                     }
                    if (txtDOB.MaskFull)
                    {
                        data.DoB = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDOB.Text);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data.DoB = null;
                    }
                    if (txtBadExp.MaskFull)
                    {
                        data.badgeExpiry = Convert.ToDateTime(txtBadExp.Text);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data.badgeExpiry = null;
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbadge.Text))
                    {
                        data.badgeID = Convert.ToInt32(txtbadge.Text);
                    }


                    data.radioSN = txtRadio.Text;
                    data.dataSN = txtVihtype.Text;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPinNo.Text))
                    {
                        data.pinNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtPinNo.Text);
                    }
                    data.plate = txtPDA.Text;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtComision.Text))
                    {
                        data.AcJobComm = Convert.ToInt32(txtComision.Text);
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtw_insure.Text))
                    {
                        data.weeklyInsurance = Convert.ToInt32(txtw_insure.Text);
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtWeekrent.Text))
                    {
                        data.weeklyRent = Convert.ToInt32(txtWeekrent.Text);
                    }
                    if (cmbSuspanded.Text == "Yes")
                    {
                        data.suspended = Convert.ToBoolean(1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data.suspended = Convert.ToBoolean(0);
                    }

                    data.driverType = cmbDtype.Text;
                    data.picturePath = txtpathnew.Text;
                    data.picture = File.ReadAllBytes(txtpathnew.Text);
                    data.AccountAllocated = txtacallocated.Text;
                    data.AccountCommission = Convert.ToInt32(txtComision.Text);
                    data.weeklyInsurance = Convert.ToInt32(cmbweeklyInsurance.Text);
                    data.rentcoded = cmbrent.Text;
                    db.Drivers.Add(data);
                    db.SaveChanges();`
```

Comment: Could you provide the inner exception.

Comment: Yes i am check inner exception. but cloud not solve it.